# Remove Fade From Flickity Slider Transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flickity

I've used flickity slider a few times, and awhile back came across a pen (may have been found on here although I can't find the question), where the slide transition uses a fade effect rather than the default effect.

The original pen is somewhat outdated (https://codepen.io/eikeco/pen/MwGRKr), but here is basically the exact same one with updated js/css.  https://codepen.io/mzq/pen/WaKvVz

The only real modification to the original slider I believe is this:

```
  .carousel-cell {
    left: 0 !important;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    z-index: -1;
    }
```

What I'd like to accomplish (if possible), but have been unable to, is change the transition so it doesn't have that blip/fade if the images or text remains the same from one slide to the next.

I generally use background images where it's more noticeable like here: https://codepen.io/mzq/pen/moyKbL

Ideally if two slides are identical there should be no noticeable transition but I also don't want it to flip instantly if they are different, which is the result I typically get. Maybe it's not possible, or not with this slider.

Comment: Somewhere you'll have to code the slider to detect the src of img or background image.

Comment: I'm not really following, the last pen does that

Comment: Here are some examples: https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/ayvZvp https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/044f4003de9aae814733411dd7600ed1 --- but I'm not sure you can get a 100% smooth crossfade. What transition timing have you tried?