# Remove fade effect completely from Flickity gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flickity

I'm using a Flickity gallery to automatic loop a series of image, however there is a fade transition between images. I'd like to remove this so that the images change instantly.

I've tried to follow the answers in this thread but they did not work.
[Remove Fade From Flickity Slider Transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54894668/remove-fade-from-flickity-slider-transitions)

I've tried adding this into the css but with no luck.

```
.carousel-cell {
  left: 0 !important;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
}

.carousel-cell.is-selected {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `transition` property, there should be no animation whatsoever. According to the fiddle in the question you provided, if you simply remove the transition, there will be no transition at all.

#### Edit:

I've checked out Flickity directly on their [website](https://flickity.metafizzy.co) and they seem to be using some javascript to animate the `transform` property. If you are using anything similar, you will have to be making modifications to javascript and not the css.